# How to theme Series when using a theme.xml in system.web.helpers.chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, themes, mschart

The support on this is currently horrible.

I'm creating my own theme for a System.Web.Helpers.Chart by using a XML file.

I've figured that the XML is basically a serialized version of the UIDataVizualazation namespace.

It works fine but I have no idea how to set theme objects tied to the Series property.

```
<Chart >
   <ChartAreas>
       <ChartArea>
            <AxisY>
                <MajorGrid />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX>
                <MajorGrid />
            </AxisX>
       </ChartArea>
   </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <Legend />
    </Legends>
</Chart>
```

This is something I can manage pretty easily but according to the Chart object System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

has a series property that is a collection of series objects and

```
<Series>
    <Series />
</Series>
```

Just doesn't do it. So if someone can point me towards a Xml schema for this or a pointer on how to access the Series property so I can change things like isValueShownAsLabel attribute I would appriciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Serialize and Deserialize Chart yourself.

Take a look here [Chart Serialization](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927183515/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021010-1.aspx)

Comment: I was just about to try to serialize the old type of chart when you pointed this to me. So this does help me but the problem now is that the Series defined in the XML come out as their own instead of being a style applied to my dynamically generated series.

Comment: Unfortunately Series class is not marked as Serializable. There are few approaches you can take here. What you can do is create a wrapper class on Series and mark it as serializable and then pass it with your chart XML

Answer (score 3):

Through experimentation I found that the case matters.

It should be:

```
<Series>
    <series>
    </series>
</Series>
```

Also this property may be of usefulness to anyone that is looking for an answer to this:

```
CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Outside"
```

Which can be placed in a series or point and perhaps other elements as well.

A list of the properties can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late to help you now but you can change series properties such as line width, colour, and labelling using

```
<Series>
    <Series Name="Default" _Template_="All" BorderWidth="3" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" />
</Series>
```